# How to display a floating point value as scientific parameter in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, floating-point, scientific-notation

We have a frequent need to display floating point values in a scientific form with multiplier and units, for example the value of 1500 V (volts) would be displayed as 1.5 kV.
A very small voltage of 1e-4 V would be displayed as 100 uV. For years we've used an internally created routine to make this float to string conversion but I was minded to wonder recently whether such a means was more generally available?

Comment: If I were you I'd carry on as you are. You are unlikely to find something that does it exactly as you desire.

Comment: I would suggest U+00B5 MICRO SIGN (µ) instead of U+0075 LATIN SMALL LETTER U (u).

Comment: Still, I completely agree with @David: there is no reason not to write such a function yourself.

Comment: @Andreas and @David - thanks, I thought as much. Brian.

Comment: @Brian In my engineering app we use engineering notation but force the exponent, if used, to be a multiple of 3. So we have our own routine that converts float to string.

Comment: By canonical means, 1e-4 V should be normalized to 0.1 mV

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this FormathWithPrefix function with little knowledge about logarithms... :)

Support [SI prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix) range!

```
function FormathWithPrefix(n: double; decimals: integer): string;
var
  index: integer;
const
  Prefixes: array[-9..9]of string = ('<', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'f', 'p', 'n', 'µ', 'm', '',
    'k','M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y', '>');   
begin
  index := round((Ln(n) / Ln(10) - 1) / 3);
  if index > 9 then 
    index := 9;
  if index < -9 then 
    index := -9;
  result := (FloatToStrF(n / Exp(index * 3 * ln(10)) , ffFixed, 20, decimals) + Prefixes[index]);
end;

begin
  n := 1500;
  Writeln(FormathWithPrefix(n, 1),'V');
```

Comment: Nice. Simliar to what we do too!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make your routines more "native", you could take a look at the ConvUtils and StdConvs units and see if you could base your routines on the conversion functions offered by these units. (Not sure when those units were introduced. Quick google search suggest Delphi 6)

But that won't necessarily achieve much for you. (Depending on what you are looking to achieve)

Comment: I'll take a look - it was something akin to a Jedi unti that I was thinking might exist. I know that Turbopower had a lot of conversions in their scientific unit years ago, but it's all pre-unicode of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try here:  http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FloatToStrF

Particularly this one:  `ShowMessage('Using 8,4 = '+FloatToStrF(amount1, ffFixed, 8, 4));
would indicate you can use something like this:

```
var 
  Answer:string;    
  thevolts:double;
begin
  Answer:= FloatToStrF(thevolts, ffFixed, 8, 4)+' kV'
end;
```

Comment: Brian knows how to convert a float to a string. He's wanting a routine that chooses V or µV as appropriate to the magnitude of the value!

Comment: @Dave   With a little ingenuity he can do exactly that with what I provided and simple routines to test for order of magnitude (number of digits) in the value.   I can and assume this is simple for a lot of us. LOL   ...hmmm if value > xxx then V else if < xx the uV  :)

Comment: he's doing what you say already. That's the kernel of his question.